# Spring Mvc async Rest Controller test fails if response comes from ExceptionHandler: asyncDispatch CountDownLatch was not set by TestDispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 2 MVC application that returns async results. Notice that although I'm using Mono it is not a webflux app but webmvc, so the result will be treated as a Spring MVC async result (Callable/DeferredResult). Besides, my controller defines a validator for the Post input:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Flux<ObjectError> exception(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    logger.error("{}", ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    return Flux.fromIterable(ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors());
}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(customerValidator);
}

@PostMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Mono<Customer> createCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer) {
    return customerService.create(customer);
}
```

When I run a test with a valid customer it passes as expected:

```
@WebMvcTest(CustomerRestController.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Import({CustomerValidator.class})
class CustomerRestControllerTests {

    @Test
    void shouldCreateNewCustomer() throws Exception {

        Customer customer = new Customer("66666D");
        given(customerService.create(customer)).willReturn(Mono.just(customer));

        MvcResult asyncResult = mockMvc
                .perform(post("/api/v1/customers")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customer))
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andReturn();

        final MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(asyncResult))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().string("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                .andReturn();

        final Customer createdCustomer = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Customer.class);
        Assertions.assertEquals(customer, createdCustomer);
    }
```

The problem is when there is a validation error. In the following test I don't set any value for the customer id. Thus, I can see the validator and then the ExceptionHandler are executed but then the test fails:

```
    MvcResult asyncResult = mockMvc
            .perform(post("/api/v1/customers")
                    .content("{}")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andReturn();

    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(asyncResult))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
```

Below is the full stack trace. With a 400 status, which is correct, but the asyncDispatcherror:

```
2018-12-26 15:06:03.714 ERROR 8836 --- [           main] c.p.p.a.c.CustomerRestController        : Validation failed for argument [0] in public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.codependent.customerspoc.dto.Customer> com.codependent.customerspoc.api.controller.CustomerRestController.createCustomer(com.codependent.customerspoc.dto.Customer) with 3 errors: [Field error in object 'Customer' on field 'nif': rejected value [null]; codes [error.validation.customer.nif.empty.Customer.nif,error.validation.customer.nif.empty.nif,error.validation.customer.nif.empty.java.lang.String,error.validation.customer.nif.empty]; arguments []; default message [null]] 

org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.codependent.customerspoc.dto.Customer> com.codependent.customerspoc.api.controller.CustomerRestController.createCustomer(com.codependent.customerspoc.dto.Customer) with 1 error: [Field error in object 'Customer' on field 'nif': rejected value [null]; codes [error.validation.customer.nif.empty.Customer.nif,error.validation.customer.nif.empty.nif,error.validation.customer.nif.empty.java.lang.String,error.validation.customer.nif.empty]; arguments []; default message [null]] 

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:71) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182) [spring-test-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.codependent.customerspoc.api.controller.CustomerRestControllerTests.shouldFailCreateNewCustomerValidation(CustomerRestControllerTests.java:174) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532) [junit-platform-commons-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]


MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/v1/customers
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
             Body = {}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.codependent.customerspoc.api.controller.CustomerRestController
           Method = public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.codependent.customerspoc.dto.Customer> com.codependent.customerspoc.api.controller.CustomerRestController.createCustomer(com.codependent.customerspoc.dto.Customer)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"scanAvailable":true,"prefetch":-1}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The asyncDispatch CountDownLatch was not set by the TestDispatcherServlet.

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.awaitAsyncDispatch(DefaultMvcResult.java:158)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.getAsyncResult(DefaultMvcResult.java:145)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.getAsyncResult(DefaultMvcResult.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.asyncDispatch(MockMvcRequestBuilders.java:269)
    at com.codependent.customerspoc.api.controller.CustomerRestControllerTests.shouldFailCreateNewCustomerValidation(CustomerRestControllerTests.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

**UPDATE:** The problem seems to be related to the async error handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public Flux<ObjectError> exception(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    logger.error("{}", ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    return Flux.fromIterable(ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors());
}
```

In this test:

```
MvcResult asyncResult = mockMvc
            .perform(post("/api/v1/customers")
                    .content("{}")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andReturn();

    final String contentAsString = asyncResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

    asyncResult.getAsyncResult();
```

contentAsString is `{"scanAvailable":true,"prefetch":-1}` and asyncResult.getAsyncResult() throws the mentioned exception.

Comment: I don't suppose that you ever solved this, did you? I have the same problem and can't see what I am supposed to set.

Comment: I couldn't make it work using reactor types in the exception handler so I changed back to return the actual objects as seen in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed changing the error handler to **return a List instead of a Flux**:

**Controller:**

```
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public List<ObjectError> exception(WebExchangeBindException ex) {
        log.error("{}", ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        return ex.getAllErrors();
    }
```

**Test class:**

```
    @Test
    void shouldFailCreateNewCustomerValidation() throws Exception {

        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(post("/api/v1/customers")
                        .content("{}")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andReturn();

        final Map[] objectErrors = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Map[].class);

        assertEquals(3, objectErrors.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`asyncDispatch CountDownLatch was not set by TestDispatcherServlet` was thrown by the test because `MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed` during `@Valid` and exception handling were not async but the test for `isBadRequest()` has been written for async case.

`asyncDispatch` is not needed in this case, the code below is sufficient:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc
  .perform(post("/api/v1/customers")
      .content("{}")
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
  .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
  .andReturn();
```

`Flux` is not causing the exception in the title, just returns `{"scanAvailable":true,"prefetch":-1}` which is not correct representation of error.